Cors issue with react, express, and discord Oauth2
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fx%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fdiscord%2Fcallback&scope=identify%20email%20guilds.members.read%20guilds.join%20guilds&client_id=x' (redirected from 'x/api/auth/discord') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
so ya ive tried a few things to try and solve the cors issue however nothing has worked. its saying im hitting the server then redirecting to discord oauth but cors is stopping me ig idk.
everything i tried failed and this is last resort

It looks like you are trying to fetch this data using fetch. This looks like an oauth login/authorization am I wrong? If it is then you should res.redirect() if in express or window.open if in client to this url and then it will send the user to an oauth screen where they can authorize the app. Then redirect back to your redirect uri.

This question is similar to: Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok since there's no code posted in your question I can only assume you are trying to authorize something for your app via Discords oauth. Probably something like login or for you to access some users data. First you need to understand the oauth2 flow. You have probably seen this a lot when using the internet and logging in via google or discord for example. Lets walk through a simple step by step. Since I don't have any of your code I will just kind of post some pseudo code for examples.

The authorization screen.

This is where the user can authorize an application to use their data. This needs to be visible to the user so you cannot call this via a javascript request you need to direct the user to this screen via a link or a redirect. I usually like to do it via redirect from express as it can keep your credentials much safer. So first let setup an endpoint for you to hit. For this example I am going to use localhost as your uri but in production you will need to swap this with your website domain.
app.get('/discord/oauth', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      response_type: 'code',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5000/discord/callback',
      scope: 'identify email guilds.members.read guilds.join guilds',
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    }

    res.redirect(`https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

If you want to do this on your client side instead of express just open this endpoint either with a link or with window.open so either <a href="http://localhost:5000/discord/oauth?put-your-params-here">Authorize App</a> or window.open("http://localhost:5000/discord/oauth?put-your-params-here"). This will direct a user to the authorization screen.
It's worth noting that usually there is a state parameter passed to the authorization uri as well and then saved to your server session. Then you can check that state when the callback is hit just to assure that it is actually the user hitting that callback url.

The callback to your app

Once the user authorizes you to use their information discord will redirect back to your site to the redirect uri you provided with an authorization code. You have 2 options to deal with this. You can either have discord redirect to your client side app and then grab the code they send you like so:
useEffect(() => {
  const query = window.location.search
  const {code} = new URLSearchParams(query);

  // process the code either in place or through an api endpoint.
}, [])

Or you can have discord redirect to a callback url on the server and then process everything there the redirect back to your client side when finished. If you choose to redirect to your client then this next bit of code would be your api endpoint. If not then the next bit of code would be your callback uri.
app.get('/discord/callback', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // use req.json() instead if calling from your client side.
    const { code } = req.query

    const params = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': 'Same redirect uri that you used in your authorization call'
    }

    const tokenRequest = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token?${new URLSearchParams(params)}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })

    const { access_token, refresh_token, token_type, expires_in, identity} = await tokenRequest.json();

    // Now you can get your data with the access_token
    const dataRequest = await fetch('whatever discord endpoint you want')
    const data = await dataRequest.json()

    // if not calling from client side then redirect back to client
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/clientPage")
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

Anyway that may have been a log winded explanation of oauth2.0. But it should give you a better idea of how this is actually implemented. This is not tested code it is just off the cuff but it should be fairly accurate. You can read the documentation here to get all of the details on how to use their oauth https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2. If you have any question which I'm sure you might hit me up in the comments below.

CORS policies are enforced by browsers to restrict web pages from making requests to servers in different domains.
A workaround would be to set up a server-side proxy/backend server. Here is an example using NodeJS:
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();

app.get('/discord/oauth', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize', {
            params: {
                response_type: 'code',
                redirect_uri: 'https://x/api/auth/discord/callback',
                scope: 'identify email guilds.members.read guilds.join guilds',
                client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
            }
        });
        res.send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send('Error');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});

Then, your client-side code can make a request to http://localhost:3000/discord/oauth, and the server will forward the request to Discord.

Another solution for development is to use the browser extension Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, which will unblock Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Im just curious. How would a user be able to authorize an app when you hit the authorization endpoint with an ajax request?
